# Node. js Nested async map with multiple http request

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Here I am trying to loop array of URLS and get the response from one set of URLs and process the response URLs . In code I want the  outer loop should enter after completing all the inner request and want the result like below.

Checking Urls in : https://stackoverflow.com
status 200 done
....
....
Checking Urls in : https://example.com
.....
.....
.....

Total links #20

But in my code outer loop is finishing before the request done.

```
const getHrefs = require('get-hrefs');
const async = require("async");
var req = require('request-promise');
var errors = require('request-promise/errors');

var pageUrls = ['https://stackoverflow.com','https://www.exsample.com'];
testUrls='';

async.map(pageUrls, function(pageUrl,callback){
    //process itemA
    req(pageUrl, function (err, response, body) {
        console.log(pageUrl, " STATUS: ", response.statusCode);
        if ( err){
            return callback(err);
        } 
        else {
        testUrls= getHrefs(response.body);

        async.map(testUrls, function(testUrl,callback1){
             linkCount++;
               req(testUrl).catch(errors.StatusCodeError, function (reason) {
                        brokenLinks++;
                        console.log("URL: "+ testUrl+ "reason: "+ reason.statusCode);
                    })
                    .catch(errors.RequestError, function (reason) {

                    }).finally(function () {


                    });

                return  callback1();
             },function(err){

                 callback();

              }) ;
        }
    })

} ,function(err){
    console.log("OuterLoopFinished");
    console.log('*************************************************************' + '\n');
    console.log('Check complete! || Total Links: ' + linkCount + ' || Broken Links: ' + brokenLinks);
    console.log('*************************************************************');

});
```

Comment: You're calling the `callback1` too early. Try putting it inside the `finally` block.

Comment: thanks for your reply, in that case  its not ending with the final call back function (outerloopfinished)

Comment: The call of `callback1` marks the end of the inner `async.map` execution (for each `testUrls` items). The completion of  `async.map(testUrls...` calls `callback` which marks the end of the outer `async.map` execution (for each `pageUrl` items). The completion of  `async.map(pageUrl...` calls the `outerloopfinished` function...

Comment: One thing to note is the `async.map` callback function (the `function(err){ "Outerloopfinished".. }` and the `function(err) { callback(); }`) is called when all iteratee functions have finished, **OR AN ERROR OCCURS** (see: https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#map). It's possible that your first `IF` branch (`if ( err){ return callback(err); }`)  invoked an early termination...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should relook at your approach. This makes 400 URLs. You should fire all request in parallel (for sublinks) and then you can track the count of broken URIs from host URL. This will complete your script faster.

```
const pageUrls = ['https://stackoverflow.com','https://www.google.com'];
const rp = require('request-promise');
const allRequestPromises = [];
const getHrefs = require('get-hrefs');

const checkBrokenCount = (url, host) => {
  rp(url).then((response) => {
    console.log('valid url', url, host);
    // other code
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('invalid url', url, host);
  });
}

pageUrls.forEach((pageUrl)=> {
  // Lets call all the base URLs in parallel asuming there are not incorrect.
  allRequestPromises.push(rp({uri: pageUrl, resolveWithFullResponse: true}));
});
Promise.all(allRequestPromises).then((responses) => {
  responses.forEach((response, index) => {
    // Promise.all guarantees the order of result.
    console.log(pageUrls[index], response.statusCode);
    const testUrls= getHrefs(response.body);
    testUrls.forEach((testUrl) => {
      checkBrokenCount(testUrl, pageUrls[index]);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response its sounds good . But how to skip the invalid base urls in promise all?

Comment: `Promise.all` is fail fast (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all#Promise.all_fail-fast_behaviour)

If you have invalid base URLs, you cannot use `Promise.all` rather use the function we already created and call it twice. Once for the base URLs and once if the response of the first request is `200`

If this helps, don't forget to upvote/accept the answer :)